# Obtain the values of another Series by the timestamps associated with a filtered Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` which I will refer to as `a` and `b`. `len(a)` returns `2400`, as does `b`. I filtered `a` by some predicate, e.g. `a[lambda x: x == 0]` and this will yield a new series where the (timestamp) indices of `a` are preserved.

```
time
2014-06-29 17:00:00    0.0
2014-06-29 18:00:00    0.0
2014-06-29 19:00:00    0.0
2014-06-29 20:00:00    0.0
2014-06-29 21:00:00    0.0
                      ... 
2014-10-15 22:00:00    0.0
2014-10-15 23:00:00    0.0
2014-10-16 00:00:00    0.0
2014-10-16 01:00:00    0.0
2014-10-16 02:00:00    0.0
Name: response, Length: 1323, dtype: float64
```

What I am seeking to do, is to look-up the values associated with these indices (timestamps) on `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for filter by `DatetimeIndex`es:

```
new = a[lambda x: x == 0]

#same working
new = a[a == 0]
b[b.index.isin(new.index)]
```